# How can I debug (GDB) the 32-bit part of a 64-bit application?

Tags: debugging, macos, gdb, osx-snow-leopard, 32bit-64bit

I have an app that is 64- and 32-bit-compatible.
If I open the app through gdb (exec-file app), it opens the 64-bit part of the app.
How can I open the 32-bit part instead?

Is there an argument that I have missed?

Comment: What are the parts you are talking about?

Comment: What operating system are you talking about? (Please mention it appropriately in the tags.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it can be done by setting a parameter for gdb:

`gdb -arch i386`